# Making URLs work locally and remotely for development

Tags: php, apache, url, hosts

I want a seamless and portable solution for local/remote web development, that allows me to use absolute URLs/URIs that work locally when on my local development environment and also work on the remote server without modification.

I already got [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) working this way, as I redirected the host name to 127.0.0.1 on my machine, and use the same host name that the remote server uses, together with same user and pass.

But when comes to HTTP, I can't of course do the same, because then I couldn't access the remote URL from the browser and in turn I would be seeing the local web server.

So is there a way?

I'm using PHP on Apache HTTP Server, and several different MVCs, WordPress, etc. so maybe doing this by code wouldn't be very portable between projects and also having a check in code that discriminates local from remote, may impact negatively on the production server performance.

I know how to do this in PHP, and I'd rather do some configuration on my local environment, so the remote server doesn't have to do extra processing for this.
Also, there are files that don't go through PHP pre-processing like .js files, that need this too.

Comment: I feel altering the hosts file and creating virtual hosts in your web server offers the most complete mock.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the hostname (or IP address) that was used to access the page. So you can make all your absolute URLs

```
$url = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/path/to/file";
```

Instead of

```
$url = "http://localhost/path/to/file";
```

This value will be taken from the `Host:` header of the HTTP request, so it will also account for non-standard ports.

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this (how you include it is up to you):

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "localhost"){
        $baseurl = "http://localhost/";
}else{
        $baseurl = "http://livesite.com/";
}
```

and then when you want to add a link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>index.html">Home</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but this would impact in the live server performance and also I have files that don't go through the PHP interpreter, like pure .js files